# How to put a TextView in the center of a ImageButton?

Tags: android

Say I have an ImageButton. I want a textview on top of the imagebutton, and centered on it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could do it by wrapping both widgets in a `FrameLayout`

for example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Are overcomplicating your layout. Just add text to the button.

```
myImageButton.setText("text");
```

If you really do want to layer these views, you should use a RelativeLayout:

```
<RealtiveLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/img"/>           
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Make a special note of the attribute `layout_centerInParent` . this is how the TextView is correctly centered.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular Button, which extends TextView anyway.  Then set the background to your image and use setText() to set your text.  You can even add icons above, below and/or left & right  of the text with the drawableLeft,drawableTop,etc attributes.